Solving heat equation using fft in python
I'm trying to implement the fast Fourier transform to solve the heat equation. The solution however makes no sense.
import numpy as np
from scipy import fft 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

# Constants
c = 1  # thermal conductivity 
L = 4    # Length of the domain
N = 100  # Number of discretization points
dx = L / N
x = np.linspace(0, L, N, endpoint=False)

kappa = 2 * np.pi * fft.fftfreq(N, d=dx)


u0 = np.zeros_like(x)
start_idx = int(1 / dx)  # Index corresponding to x = 2
end_idx = int(3 / dx)   # Index corresponding to x = 10
u0[start_idx:end_idx] = 1  # Set the pulse between x = 2 and x = 10


def RHSheatspatial(t, u, kappa, c):
    uhat = fft.fft(u)
    dd_uhat = -np.power(kappa, 2) * uhat
    dd_u = fft.ifft(dd_uhat)
    du_dt = -c**2 * dd_u
    return np.real(du_dt)

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000) 

sol = solve_ivp(RHSheatspatial, (0, 10), u0, method='RK45', args=(kappa, c), t_eval=t,rtol=1.0e-6,atol=1.0e-8)
print(sol)

# Initial condition
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(x, u0, label='Initial Condition', color='blue')
plt.title('Initial Condition')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('T')
plt.grid(True)

# Final solution at t = 1
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(x, sol.y[:, -1], label='Final Solution at t=1', color='red')
plt.title('Solution at t=10')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('T')
plt.grid(True)

message: Required step size is less than spacing between numbers.
success: False
status: -1
t: [ 0.000e+00  1.001e-02  2.002e-02  3.003e-02  4.004e-02
5.005e-02  6.006e-02  7.007e-02  8.008e-02  9.009e-02
1.001e-01  1.101e-01]
y: [[ 0.000e+00 -3.478e+22 ... -2.198e+254 -1.248e+280]
[ 0.000e+00  1.042e+23 ...  6.584e+254  3.740e+280]
...
[ 0.000e+00  1.042e+23 ...  6.584e+254  3.740e+280]
[ 0.000e+00 -3.478e+22 ... -2.198e+254 -1.248e+280]]
sol: None
t_events: None
y_events: None
nfev: 16994
njev: 0
nlu: 0


Do you have a minus sign to much in your RHSheatspatial? When I remove one of them, i.e., du_dt = c**2 * dd_u, I get the following solution:

I am not sure if this is the correct solution to your heat equation, though, but it looks more plausible, I believe.

That does look much more plausible; the goal was to just capture a general trend. Thank you !!!
